# Number of cpus and cores in macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, virtualization, cpu

On Macbook Pro, I clicked "about this mac", and it shows that

> Number of Processors:   1
>     Total Number of Cores:  2

I thought I have more cores and cpus, because when I created a virtual machine in Virtualbox, it allows me to specify up to 4 cpus to the virtual machine.

So how can I find out the number of cpus and cores on this laptop?

`lshw` doesn't work in bash under Mac. Is there some similar command?

Thanks.

Comment: Those are **virtual CPU cores** that VirtualBox is showing and the general rule of thumb is is to not assign more then half of the virtual CPU cores available, thus allow the Host to maintain good functionality while simultaneously running the virtual machine.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is to launch Activity Monitor - in Applications/Utilities

Then hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  which will open the CPU History.
Then you just count the stripes ;-)
It counts virtual cores, so includes HT [Hyper-threading] cores.

[image]